# What does index do in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have a code I'm working with which has the following line,

```
data2 <- apply(data1[,-c(1:(index-1))],2,log)
```

I understand that this creates a new data frame, from the data1, taking column-wise values log-transformed and some columns are eliminated, but I don't understand how the columns are removed. what does 1:(index-1) do exactly?

Comment: Presumably `index` is a variable you have previously defined in your code. It is not a special keyword in R.

Answer (score 2):

The ":" operator creates an integer sequence. Because `(1:(index-1) )` is numeric and being used in the second position for the extraction operator"[" applied to a dataframe, it is is referring to column numbers. The person writing the code didn't need the `c`-function. It could have been more economically written:

```
data1[,-(1:(index-1))]  
# but the outer "("...")"'s are needed so it starts at 1 rather than -1
```

So it removes the first `index-1` columns from the object passed to `apply`. (As MrFlick points out, index must have been defined before this gets passed to R. There's not default value or interpretation for `index` in R.

Comment: Thank you! index was predefined in the code, I happened to have missed it while re-running.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the index is 5, then index -1 returns 4 so the sequence will be from 1 to 4 i.e. and then we use `-` implies loop over the columns other than the first 4 columns as `MARGIN = 2`